# Yandex mapkit setNightMode() не работает

Tags: android, yandexmapkit

В Yandex mapkit есть класс MapController у которого есть метод setNightMode

> setNightMode
>
> public void setNightMode(boolean flag) Turns the night mode on.
>
> Parameters: flag -

Когда я пытаюсь использовать этот метод

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_yandex_map, container, false);
        final MapView mapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapController = mapView.getMapController();
        mOverlayManager = mMapController.getOverlayManager();
        mMapController.setNightMode(true);
        return view;
    }
```

Я получаю ошибку в строке `mMapController.setNightMode(true);`.

```
03-16 10:08:48.326 1998-1998/com.shwalabaka.myyandexmap E/art: No implementation found for void ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.utils.Utils.InvertBitmapNative(short[], int) (tried Java_ru_yandex_yandexmapkit_utils_Utils_InvertBitmapNative and Java_ru_yandex_yandexmapkit_utils_Utils_InvertBitmapNative___3SI)
03-16 10:08:48.326 1998-1998/com.shwalabaka.myyandexmap D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-16 10:08:48.328 1998-1998/com.shwalabaka.myyandexmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                          Process: com.shwalabaka.myyandexmap, PID: 1998
                                                                          java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.utils.Utils.InvertBitmapNative(short[], int) (tried Java_ru_yandex_yandexmapkit_utils_Utils_InvertBitmapNative and Java_ru_yandex_yandexmapkit_utils_Utils_InvertBitmapNative___3SI)
                                                                              at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.utils.Utils.InvertBitmapNative(Native Method)
                                                                              at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.utils.Utils.a(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at ax.b(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at ax.c(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapModel.setNightMap(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapModel.setNightMode(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at ru.yandex.yandexmapkit.MapController.setNightMode(Unknown Source)
                                                                              at com.shwalabaka.myyandexmap.YandexMapFragment.onCreateView(YandexMapFragment.java:39)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:339)
                                                                              at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:602)
                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1236)
                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6006)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Возможно ли выставить ночной режим карты в Yandex mapkit?

Comment: попробуйте перенести mMapController.setNightMode(true) в onResume

Comment: пробовал перенести в onResume(), а так же запускать по клику по кнопке выдает ту же ошибку.

Comment: https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/issues/206

Answer (score 1):

Это был баг старой версии. В новой исправили

https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandexmapkit-android/issues/206

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас ночной режим включается по-другому

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:maps.mobile:4.0.0-lite'


mapview = view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mapview.getMap().setNightModeEnabled(true);
```